# Selenium: Chrome in Docker Container: Take screenshot?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker

I am using the official selenium chrome driver Image: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/

Unfortunately, I am unable to take screenshots in the container.

This code works perfectly ok outside of the container:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.save_screenshot("some_file.png")
driver.close()
```

but in the container, save_screenshot returns false.
I found a small hint in the github of chrome, that screensize and depth must be set, but setting them to 1920 * 1080 * 24 did not change anythign

Comment: Elaborate your setup. Where are you running the code? Is Docker run in container?

Comment: Try with https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium or with https://github.com/zalando/zalenium

Comment: I had the same problem, and changed to use `Firefox()` instead. I install both `geckodriver` and `firefox` in the container, and then were able to take a screenshot.

Comment: Christian,
Did you figure it out? I can't get Chrome nor Firefox to takeScreenshot in my docker container with selenium grid. Can you share your code on how to get it to work? Thanks.

Comment: @seleniumappiumnewbie Now, I did not figure it out :(

Comment: @ChristianSauer Please update your question. Show us the full error or exception from Selenium

Comment: @TalAngel Honestly, whjy do you necro such old stuff?

Comment: @ChristianSauer LOL, did not notice this question is 5 years old. Yet, it's better late than never.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with containers, then you should consider using fully separated browser containers. Selenoid (or its Kubernetes version, Moon) utilizes the Selenium Grid mechanism for this purpose. This means that the only thing required in your code is to specify the Selenium Hub server and the desired version of the browser.

```py
    capabilities = {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "version": "109.0"
    }
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
        desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Remote driver fully supports taking screenshots from any browser and you do not need to worry about maintaining browser drivers and browsers.

Official webpage: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/